# difference image in showing in Matplotlib and Streamlit

Tags: matplotlib, streamlit, grayscale

When I plotting a slice of `CT` with `Matplotlib` and `Streamlit` they show differently that slice. In below I plotting them:

`plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')`
[image]

`st.image(img, clamp=True)`
[image]

`st..image(img.astype(np.uint8))`
[image]

As you can see the matplotlib show the best one. How can set streamlit to show this images like matplotlib?